# Downsides of having a unique url for users?

Tags: web-applications, url-routing

I allow users to have a unique keyword that allowed their profile page to be accessed by mysite.com/username. I'm using a line at the bottom of my routing rules file to catch these urls. I then look up the username in my database and redirect them if necessary.

Is there any downside to doing this? One thing I noticed is that every bad link hits my database first.

Also, what do I do in the case that I "need" the URL? For example, if a user registers "about" as their unique name. I later realize I need that url. What do I do?